# How to Extract Data in a string in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have some data as aaa.4A.aa, 4A-AAA, AAA/4A, AA.a.4.A.AA in excel and I want to extract only 4A from all these strings in Excel.

I have tried with substitute and replace with find functions.

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("4a",A2)),"4A"

I want 4A from all the above mentioned string in excel. Help me with the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("4a",A2))),"4A","")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the above formula works for 3 strings mentioned in question but its not working for the string AA.a.4.A.AA or aa/4-a.AA

Comment: can any one help on the above question.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, i need to get the data 4A from any word which contains these 2 characters and i got answer for 3 words, i mean for these aaa.4A.aa, 4A-AAA, AAA/4A but i'm not getting for this word AA.a.4.A.AA.